# Security For Custom Application Pages

Tags: security, custom, application-pages

When managing security for any control on a page we use `SPSecurityTrimmedControl`. But what to do when defining permissions for a custom application page?

How do we restrict unauthorized people to access some custom application pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible duplicate of the question, [Can an Application Page Permissions Be Set from SharePoint Foundation 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/can-an-application-page-permissions-be-set-from-sharepoint-foundation-2010)

Answer from post:

> Permissions for application pages are normally set within the
>   application page itself, using the `RightsRequired` property.
>
> Here's a comprehensive blog post about Application Page security:
>   http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/10/sharepoint-application-page-security.html

Also, have a look at below post:
[Securing SharePoint Application Pages](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/10/15/secure-a-sharepoint-application-page.aspx)