# How to secure the application pages in SharePoint 2013 with Claims authentication

Tags: claims-based-auth, authorization

I want to secure the application pages in SharePoint 2013 with Claims authentication, it does not seem to be working.

```
<configuration>
   <location path="_layouts/15/settings">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="demo\user1"/>
            <deny users="*" />
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

however it works on Windows based authentication.

**Update: 20-May-15:**

I have fixed this

```
    <configuration>
       <location path="_layouts/15/settings">
          <system.web>
             <authorization>
                <allow users="0#.w|demo\user1"/>
                <deny users="*" />
             </authorization>
          </system.web>
       </location>
</configuration>
```

however I could not allow the AD group to have access.

How do I authorize both the individual user and AD groups

Comment: check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53749/security-for-custom-application-pages

Comment: I may also have to secure the default application pages like viewlsts.aspx, settings.aspx & etc., can we do this with IIS/asp.net authorization?